# Plagiarism detection with Python

Tags: python, nlp, fuzzy-logic

## Background

Using Python, I need to score the existence of a quote, containing around 2-7 words, a longer text. The quote doesn't have to match the text precisely, but similar words should have the *same order*.

For example, given the following **long text**:

> The most beautiful things in the world cannot be seen or touched, they are felt with the heart

The following quotes should be scored **high** (say, above 80 / 100):

> The beautiful thing in our world
>
> World cannot see
>
> They feel with the heart

Since they are not precise, but they preserve the order.

While, on the other hand, these quotes should be scored **lower** (say, below 50 / 100):

> The beautiful heart cannot be felt or seen
>
> They are the most seen in the world
>
> These words don't even appear on this text

Because (the first 2) appear entirely in the text, but do not preserve the order.

## The problem

This task cannot be accomplished by simply checking the existence of each word in the text. I don't know which algorithm fits best for this task.

## What I have tried

Most of the functions in `fuzzywuzzy` (`partial_token_sort_ratio`, `token_sort_ratio` and etc) scored the later terms higher.
`partial_ratio` did score the earlier terms higher, but the quote

> These words don't even appear on this text

Got 52 / 100 which is unreasonably high.

## My question

How can I use python to score the existence of short quotes in longer texts as mentioned above?

Comment: Did you read [the literature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism_detection)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's [fuzzywuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) uses Levenshtein Distance which looks at character level differences.

You have to explore other approaches to text similarity. Find algorithms that nonlinearly weight n-grams differences, such as [Q-gram](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397592901434).

[python-string-similarity repo](https://github.com/luozhouyang/python-string-similarity) has implementations of many text similarity algorithms.